# Overfitting in a model training

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, multilabel-classification

I am trying to train a CNN model on a dataset of 3002 pictures, for the training I am using both of validation and training set and I have to do classification on 90 classes.

The classes are not balanced, I tried to do some augmentation but it's not sufficient so I used the cross entropy with weights to manage the imbalance data during training and validation.

For the plots I tried to plot the loss and accuracy accros epochs but I don't know if the model is well trained or is overfitting, plus it converges quickly, for example if I am using 40 epochs it reaches accuracy of 70 through the 11th epoch.

And another question, how to choose the right number of epochs after analysing the plots ?

[Loss function for validation and training](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwsJK.jpg)

[Accuracy for validation and training](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4DW3.jpg)

Comment: From what I see, both are pretty good graphs. You can use callbacks like EarlyStopping, basically meaning if the accuracy/loss remains the same even after 'n' epochs, the training will stop causing less overfit. On top of this, keep the evaluation metrics as F1 score apart from Accuracy to have much better results.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, so you think that the gap between the validation and training plots is not huge? Because I saw examples where they are very similar so I got confused

Comment: Yes, in ideal conditions, they should go hand in hand. If validation accuracy starts crossing training accuracy on the upside, its overfit and vice versa for underfit. Usually, val accuracy should be close to training accuracy. 
To understand this even better, check F1 for each class and plot the ROC Curve, and see how it is converging.

Answer (score 0):

When you achieve a lower loss on the validation dataset, you can save the model parameters using `torch.save`. The saved model is the best one, and you can also print the epoch number during the training. You can confirm that the model is overfitting when the training loss continues to decrease while the validation loss does not.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend splitting the data into three subsets: training, validation, and testing. Use the test dataset to evaluate the model's performance.

Meanwhile, use the validation dataset to monitor when to stop the learning process. The code below demonstrates how to implement an early stopping mechanism using the max_patience parameter. For example, if the validation loss does not decrease for 3 consecutive epochs, the training process will be interrupted. It's important to save the best model with minimal validation loss during training:

```
    if val_loss < min_val_loss:
        min_val_loss = val_loss
        patience = 0  
    else:
        patience += 1  

    if patience >= max_patience:
        print("Stopping early due to lack of improvement in validation loss.")
        break
```

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer, actually I am doing the same thing but I am using accuracy as a reference and as I am working with imbalanced classes I thought maybe F1 score will be a good reference too to evaluate the model, would you like to tell Which one to choose please between loss function, accuracy and F1 score?

Comment: you can consider acc weighed, f1, roc auc(one to all) as metric for monitoring, i recommend to use loss function changes for detection overfit, if you chose right loss function for your task, so loss function has correlation with your metric and it's good to use adaptive learning rate when you loss function changes stuck